# "short s = 2;" O Java já entende o 2 como short?

Tags: java, tipagem, literal

Sei que por padrão ao inicializar uma variável de um tipo inteiro o Java o classifica como `int`, mas no caso de `short s = 2`, o Java já entende o 2 como `short`? Ou há alguma conversão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há conversão, mas há um *cast* implícito, então apesar de tecnicamente o seu literal ser um `int`, se ele puder ser considerado um `short` isto será feito pelo compilador na hora de gerar o código. O compilador sabe entender o `int` como se fosse um `short` sem custo algum. Um *cast*  pode ser realizado pelo compilador sem implicar em código a ser executado, portanto sem conversão. Na memória será reservado apenas 2 bytes e o número será codificado desta forma sem perdas ou conversões (se couber na faixa deste tipo, não pode fazer isto se o número fugir da faixa).

Nem todo *cast* gera conversão, o compilador faz esforço para apenas interpretar da forma diferente que ele precisa naquele contexto, em alguns casos não sendo possível ele fará uma conversão, mas não é este caso, ele sabe que pode só interpretar aquele número como um `short`.

Comment: Maniero, não entendi o começo da sua explicação. Se há um cast, então há um conversão, não?

Comment: Não, se *cast* fosse sempre uma conversão chamaria *conversion* e não *cast*. Provavelmente você não entende o que é um *cast*.

Comment: Então,pelo site que estou estudando o autor fala em conversão. Inclusive ele diz que não há operação de cast. Ele apenas diz que o java entende que é short porque o tipo é short (falando de um valor que está entre os valores que um short pode representar). Posso saber a referência que você utilizou para sua resposta?

Comment: Você pediu referência para quem está te ensinando errado? Provavelmente ele também não sabe o que é um *cast*, sugiro procurar uma fonte melhor. Se há uma operação sendo feita ele deveria provar isso. É muito mais difícil pra eu provar algo que não acontece. *Cast* é algo que pode só o compilador aplicar, não executa nada https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Literal, shttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294934/setting-short-value-java#comment2259689_2294977, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193983/221800